# Compare real analysis textbooks

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I want to self study Real Analysis, and I want to choose between these books.

This is my background

I am a teacher of mathematics for highschool, which means (at least) in my country, that I had seen abstract algebra untill ring theory and calculus untill integral in several variables, but not things like Stokes theorem (because standards for teachers in my country solicites some very basic ODE and, so I had seen ODE instead Stokes). This calculus class was a mix level between engineering and pure mathematics

Could you tell me about the pros and cons of each of the following Real Analysis books? (Suitable or not for self-study, content quality, difficulty of the exercises, etc.)

- ***Real Mathematical Analysis***, by Charles Pugh
- ***Mathematical Analysis***, by Tom Apostol
- ***Principles of Mathematical Analysis***, by Walter Rudin

Comment: What book is right for you depends a lot on your background. You can ease our work by telling us a little more about your current level of knowledge and experience reading math books.

Comment: @thomas andrews I am a teacher of mathematics for highschool, which means (at least) in my country, that I had seen abstract algebra untill ring theory and calculus untill integral in several variables, but not things like Stokes theorem (because standards for teachers in my country solicites some very basic EDO and, so I had seen EDO instead Stokes).  This calculus class was a mix level between engineering and pure mathematics

Comment: I don't know if you already considered it, but if not Tao's analysis was a beautiful experience for me.

Comment: @Promethèus what do you think about exercises level in Tao?

Comment: Rudin's book is fairly standard and has a lot of really good resources for self study, in my experience. Not sure about the other two books you mentioned, but the same for them might be true. I know that Rudin's book is also typically used in undergraduate level analysis classes (at least in the US), so might be a good introduction if you are looking for something without measure theory.

Comment: Pugh's book is Rudin 2.0. That is, it covers the same topics (even chapters are the same) but it has a lot of examples, discussion, and motivation. If you want to study on your own then I would suggest Pugh.

Comment: @RicardoMejíasConstanzo Exercise level in Tao's analysis can vary wildely from trivial to challenging imo. One thing to note is that all exercises are proofs whith almost no exceptions whereas other books offer also different type of exercises. Overall I think the exercises, as ususal in math books, play an incredibly important role and I found Tao's choice of exercises to be very useful for me at my level.

Comment: Put the details in your question. People shouldn't have to read through comments to get a complete question. @RicardoMejíasConstanzo

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas said, background matters a lot and well resources too.

Real mathematical analysis by Charles Pugh:

Pros : Pugh's real analysis is a fantastic book filled with lots of exercises/pictures. Difficulty of exercises range from easy to really hard. Book is readable as well.

Cons : Solution manual isn't available (Author did that on purpose though -.-, read the preface) Other than math forums, it's quite difficult to find solutions of the problems.

Rudin's Principles of Real analysis :
(What I'm currently using.)

Really good exercises. Yes, Rudin's tough, but i believe that if you supplement your text with some lectures notes or lectures you will gain a lot, trust me here.

The supplements i suggest are :
(Solely for Rudin)
[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~auroux/112s19/Notes_Math_112_may5.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eauroux/112s19/Notes_Math_112_may5.pdf) (*45 pages) and
https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_L/analysis_i.pdf (*61 pages)

Now, Rudin(book) is dry, there aren't many examples or easier problems to get familiar with definitions or theorems,  it throws a mountain of tough things at you. So these will will help as well.

Um, If it's for self study, Abbot's Real analysis will do the job as well, and it's a good read.

Comment: Do you mean Stephen Abbott, *Understanding Analysis*?

Comment: Regarding @Calum Gilhooley's comment, which just happened to be posted a handful of minutes before I clicked on this question, Abbott's book is not very equivalent to any of the three books the OP is interested in, as Abbott's book is a significant drop down from Pugh, Apostol, Rudin (roughly equivalent to one year of undergraduate study/maturity). Also, Abbott's book is primarily for 1-semester courses, whereas Pugh, Apostol, Rudin are primarily for 2-semester courses (unless a lot of skipping is done, or the pace is rapid).